# Add additional string to printing

Tags: matlab

Hi I would to print a string while adding the dots to the end rather than reprinting the string every time before it prints out the string again and again. I want it to print but only adding the dots to the already printed out string.

```
reboot = '### rebooting the mmp';
        display(reboot)

        for i = 1 : 15
            reboot = strcat(reboot,'.')
            pause(1);
        end
```

How would i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than printing out the entire string every time, you can just print out a new dot each time through the loop.

To make this work, you'll want to use `fprintf` to print the dot rather than `disp` since `disp` will automatically append a newline to the end and `fprintf` will not so all of the dots end up on the same line.

```
% Print the initial message without a trailing newline
fprintf('### rebooting the mmp');

% Print 5 dots all on the same line with a 1-second pause
for k = 1:5
    fprintf('.')
    pause(1)
end

% We DO want to print a newline after we're all done
fprintf('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf(reboot)
for i=1:15
    fprintf('.')
    pause(1)
end
```